# If $F(U)⊂ U$, then $ϕ : V/U → V/U , v + U → f(v) + U $?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, equivalence-relations

The is given vector space $V$ through a field $K$ and f: $V  → V$ is an Endomorphism. Furthermore, $ U ⊂ V $ is a vector subspace and $ξ: V  → V/U$ the canonical projection. Please prove that there exists an Endomorphism $ϕ : V/U → V/U$ with $ϕ ◦ ξ = ξ ◦ f$ if and only if $F(U)⊂ U.$

The official solution start like that:

First of all $F(U)⊂ U.$ is true. Then the mapping

$ϕ : V/U → V/U , v + U → f(v) + U $

is well defined.

I got informed that $V/U$ consists of equivalence classes with  $v∼w$ iff $v−w∈U$. So in particular $[v]$ can be seen as $v+U$. What I don't understand is $U+f(v)$ How do we know that $v + U → f(v) + U $? If $ϕ : V/U → V/U , $, shouldn't it be just $v + U → w + U $ with $v,w ∈ V$?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Well, what is $V/U$?

Comment: @Hetebrij it is the relative complement of U in V. (You "substract" U from V). As a result you get all the elements that are in V but not in U.

Comment: No, that is $V\backslash U$. $V/U$ consists of equivalence classes with $v \sim w$ iff $v-w \in U$. So in particular $[v]$ can be seen as $v +U$.

Comment: You're right. $V/U$ consists of equivalence classes with $v∼w$ if and only if $v-w ∈ U$

Comment: So, now I understand $v + U$ If we add $v$ to all elements of $U$ we get a bunch of vectors which are $∼v$. Do I get it right? What I still don't understand is that $f(v) + U$. I know that we get a bunch of vectors which are $∼f(v)$, but why they should be  $∼f(v)$? Shouldn't be there just some $w∈V$ vector? How do we know that $f(v)=v?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we define $\phi : V/U \to V/U, v+U \mapsto f(v)+U$.
Formally we have $V/U = \{ [v] \mid v \in V \}$ with $[v] = \{ w \in V \mid v - w \in U \}$. However, we can show that $v +U := \{ v+ u \mid u \in U \} $ is equal to $[v]$.

So we define $\phi([v]) = f(v) +U$. However, this is only well-defined if $\phi([w]) = f(v) + U$ for all $w \in [v]$, since then $[v] = [w]$.
So let $w \in [v]$, then we have $w = v +u$ for some $u \in U$ and thus
\begin{align}
\phi([w]) = f(w) + U = f(v+u) + U = f(v) + f(u) + U = f(v) +U
\end{align}
where we used $f(v+u) = f(v) +f(u)$ as $f$ is an endomorphism and $f(U) \subset U$, thus $f(u) \in U$ as $u\in U$.
As $U$ is a subspace, so $f(u) + U = \tilde{u} + U = U$.

So regardless of the representative $w$ of $[v]$, we have $\phi([v]) = f(v)  +U = [f(v)]$, and thus $\phi$ is well-defined.

And we choose $\phi([v])$ to be $[f(v)]$, as we then have
\begin{align}
\xi \circ f(v) = \xi(f(v)) = [f(v)] = \phi([v]) = \phi(\xi(v) = \phi \circ \xi (v),
\end{align}
i.e. $\xi \circ f = \phi \circ \xi$ as we wanted to show.